# Should a US dual-citizen with no ties in the US submit form 2555 with "bona fide" or "physical presence" test?

Tags: usa, taxes, us-citizens, dual-citizenship

[Form 2555](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-2555) can be submitted with either "Bona Fide Residence Test" or "Physical Presence Test". Which option should be chosen by a dual-citizen who never had any ties in the US?

Answer (score 4):

Whichever one is easier to prove.  The most likely criterion for judging which one is easier to prove is the amount of evidence that must be submitted.  That in turn will depend on the person's circumstances.